# can't query from dbpedia with a sparql

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

I want to query from dbpedia using their sparql interface (http://dbpedia.org/sparql)

I want to get the abstract of

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/Herbie_Mann
```

I know that I have to call abstract ontology

```
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract
```

and my final sparsql query is like following :

```
SELECT ?abstract
WHERE {
{ <http://dbpedia.org/page/Herbie_Mann> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?abstract}
}
```

but yet I'm not able to see anything.

please help me as I am beginner in semantic web!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got my answer

the problem :

```
http://dbpedia.org/page/Herbie_Mann
```

it should be

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Herbie_Mann
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `<.../page/Herbie_Mann>` but `<.../resource/Herbie_Mann>`. The first URI is just the URL of the HTML page that describes the artist. You are interested in the properties of the artist himself. The second URI is the URI that identifies the artist.

Comment: You beat me to it by 22 seconds! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try this query instead, where the URI for Herbie Mann includes /resource instead of /page:

```
SELECT ?abstract
WHERE { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Herbie_Mann> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract>?abstract
}
```